# CodeBlocks: how can I import a project that runs with a makefile for debugging?

Tags: c++, makefile, codeblocks

So I have a school project that doesn't seem to have a main method. It is instead has a bunch of ".cc", ".o", ".d", etc files and we run it with "make clean test" on the linux command line.

I have no idea how to import this into CodeBlocks so that i can do the same thing, but debug easier than with GDB. When I try to add all the same files with the same structure, it doesnt run because it cant find a main method.

Is there a way to configure CodeBlocks so that I can just import this project and use it with its makefile, without having to make a main method?

Edit: Here is the makefile

```
all : kernel.img

-include ../common.mak

kernel : Makefile $(OFILES) $(CFILES) $(SFILES) $(CCFILES)
    ld -T script.ld -N -m elf_i386 -e start -o kernel $(OFILES)

clean ::
    rm -f kernel
```

Comment: `.cc` is an extension sometimes used for c++ files (as an alternative to `.cpp`). If you really can't open it in codeblocks try another editor or rename it to `.cpp`. `.d` and `.o` files are generated during compilation.

Comment: It does open in codeblocks. It just doesnt run because there is no main method. It is run through makefile commands.

Comment: It's possible the make file is referencing code at a different location or even a library that contains a `main()`. Does the project compile to an executable or a library?

Comment: I think an issue might be that when I add the files, it isnt keeping the directory structure. It is having alot of trouble finding header files that are in another folder. I thought CodeBlocks would be able to do this itself.

Comment: Sounds like the instructor is hiding the test cases from you. Easiest thing to do is infer the test cases and reimplement them in your own `main`. Those .o files are going to be compiler-dependent and may not work with the tool chain your copy of code::blocks is using..

Comment: Adding the makefile to your question will probably make this easier for us to help you work out.

Comment: I added the makefile. I'm sorry I cant provide more detailed info. This is a class assignment.

Comment: There is a makefile in the kernel directory. Maybe you should inspect that makefile instead of this one. make -C kernel $@ points to that makefile.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I edited my code to show the more relevent makefile.